# Android: ImageView in center screen

Tags: android, image, imageview, screen, center

I have a background image in full screen with a `RelativeLayout`. And other image (100x100) in an `ImageView`.

I want to put the `ImageView` in center screen. But my image shows top left.

What is the problem?

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fondo_inicio" >

<ImageView android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/icono_inicio"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this to your `ImageView`

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the ImageView.

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fondo_inicio" >

<ImageView android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:background="@drawable/icono_inicio"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

User `layout_gravity` and `gravity` doesn't work in case of `RelativeLayout` so just use

```
Layout_centerInParent = "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/pic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```